# No puedo capturar correctamente una excepción en java

Tags: java, excepciones

Hola tengo un problema con lo siguiente:
tengo este metodo donde guardo un usuario en la base de datos:

```
public void nuevoUsuario(Usuario usuario) throws SQLException {
    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empresa", "root", "ticowrc2017");
        String sentencia = "INSERT INTO usuario (Cedula_Usuario,Nombre, Usuario, Contrasena, Rol) "
                + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sentencia);
        ps.setString(1, usuario.getCedulaUsuario());
        ps.setString(2, usuario.getNombre());
        ps.setString(3, usuario.getUsuario());
        ps.setString(4, usuario.getContrasena());
        ps.setInt(5, usuario.getRol());
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El usuario ya está registrado o uno de los campo\n"
                + "que ha llenado han sido ingresados en otro usuario");
    } finally {
        try {
            ps.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DATUsuario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

También este otro método

```
public void nuevoUsuario() {
    int rolUs = 0;
    int digitosCedula = txtCedulaUser.getText().length();
    if (txtConf.getText().isEmpty() || txtNombre.getText().isEmpty()
            || txtPass.getText().isEmpty() || txtUsuario.getText().isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Todos los campos son obligatorios");
    } else if (digitosCedula != 10) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Número de cédula incorrecto");
    } else {
        String cedula = txtCedulaUser.getText();
        String nom = txtNombre.getText();
        String usu = txtUsuario.getText();
        String pass = txtPass.getText();
        String rol = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        if (rol.equals("Vendedor")) {
            rolUs = 0;
        }
        if (txtPass.getText().equals(txtConf.getText())) {
            String newPass = pass;
            pass = getMD5(newPass);
            objUs = new Usuario(cedula, nom, usu, pass, rolUs);
            try {
                usuario.nuevoUsuario(objUs);
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
            }
            this.dispose();
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las contraseñas no coinciden");
        }
    }
}
```

Y este evento:

```
 private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    nuevoUsuarioVendedor();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
                null, "El usuario se creó correctamente, "
                + "a continuación deberá \nvolver a ingresar "
                + "su usuario y contraseña");
        Validacion objV = new Validacion();
        objV.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
}
```

Bien ahora el problema es que, después de que el programa captura la excepcion me ejecuta el mensaje de que el usuario se creó correctamente y no deberia pasar eso (al menos eso pienso yo) ¿Como deberia hacer para que despues de que capture la excepcion no muestre el mensaje de que el usuario se creó correctamente?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer que tu metodo retorne true si inserto bien o false si no inserto bien, asi:

```
   public boolean nuevoUsuario(Usuario usuario) throws SQLException {
        try {
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/empresa", "root", "ticowrc2017");
            String sentencia = "INSERT INTO usuario (Cedula_Usuario,Nombre, Usuario, Contrasena, Rol) "
                    + "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sentencia);
            ps.setString(1, usuario.getCedulaUsuario());
            ps.setString(2, usuario.getNombre());
            ps.setString(3, usuario.getUsuario());
            ps.setString(4, usuario.getContrasena());
            ps.setInt(5, usuario.getRol());
            int cant = ps.executeUpdate();

    return cant > 0;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "El usuario ya está registrado o uno de los campo\n"
                    + "que ha llenado han sido ingresados en otro usuario");
    return false;
        } finally {
            try {
                ps.close();
                con.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(DATUsuario.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }


    public void nuevoUsuario() {
        int rolUs = 0;
        int digitosCedula = txtCedulaUser.getText().length();
        if (txtConf.getText().isEmpty() || txtNombre.getText().isEmpty()
                || txtPass.getText().isEmpty() || txtUsuario.getText().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Todos los campos son obligatorios");
        } else if (digitosCedula != 10) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Número de cédula incorrecto");
        } else {
            String cedula = txtCedulaUser.getText();
            String nom = txtNombre.getText();
            String usu = txtUsuario.getText();
            String pass = txtPass.getText();
            String rol = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
            if (rol.equals("Vendedor")) {
                rolUs = 0;
            }
            if (txtPass.getText().equals(txtConf.getText())) {
                String newPass = pass;
                pass = getMD5(newPass);
                objUs = new Usuario(cedula, nom, usu, pass, rolUs);
                try {


if(usuario.nuevoUsuario(objUs)) {
 //Mostrar el mensaje de que se guardo correctamente.
}
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
                }
                this.dispose();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Las contraseñas no coinciden");
            }
        }
    }
```

En el evento quita el mensaje

```
 private void btnGuardarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    nuevoUsuarioVendedor();
        objV.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
}
```